# Having two results in false section of ifelse statement in r

Tags: r, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a conditional statement:

```
conditional<-ifelse(AtoB,print('true'),(n<-n+0 & list[n]))
```

My goal is to print out two different results if the statement AtoB is false. How do I format this in a one line code. The error that comes up is:

```
Error in n + 0 & ONE[n] : 
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Also if anyone knows the answer, instead of printing out n<-n+0, I would like to just store that if the conditional statement is false rather than producing an output.

Either option would work but help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of `& list[n]`?

Comment: Please update your question with example data (`AtoB`, `n`, `list`) and describe exactly what output you would want to see for that particular input. Right now it's difficult to understand what you want the code to actually do. Also, it would be best if you picked a name other than `list` to avoid clobbering the built-in `list` function.

Comment: Creating a data-object with the name list doe not "clobber the `list` function". Functions and data-objects are stored separately and if one specifies a name followed by the "[" operator(function) the interpreter with return the data-object. Only if one follows the name with an open-paren will the list-function be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appears to me that you are making the opposite error that most new users of R commit. They generally reach for `if(test ){conseq}else{alter}` when they want to run a series of tests on a single vector and get results as a single vector. You apparently want something else (actions and multi-item lists) and probably (almost surely in fact) *should* be using the `if(){}else{}` construct.

```
 conditional <- if( AtoB ) {print('true')} else{ list(n =n+0 , list[n])}
```

If AtoB is a series of values then you will need to iterator over them and concatenate the results. (And you should remember that `print` will return its value as well as cause a side-effect.)